# Scikit learn algorithms performing extremely poorly

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm new to scikit learn and I'm banging my head against the wall. I've used both real world and test data and the scikit algorithms are not performing above chance level in predicting anything. I've tried knn, decision trees, svc and naive bayes.

Basically, I made a test data set consisting of a column of 0s and 1s, with all the 0s having a feature between 0 and .5 and all the 1s having a feature value between .5 and 1. This should be extremely easy and give near 100% accuracy. However, none of the algorithms are performing above chance level. Accurasies range from 45 to 55 %. I've already tried tweaking a whole bunch of parameters for every algorithm but noting helps. I think something is fundamentally wrong with my implementation.

Please help me out. Here's my code:

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
import sklearn
import pandas
import numpy as np


df=pandas.read_excel('Test.xlsx') 



# Make data into np arrays
y = np.array(df[1])
y=y.astype(float) 
y=y.reshape(399)

x = np.array(df[2])
x=x.astype(float) 
x=x.reshape(399, 1)



# Creating training and test data

labels_train, labels_test = train_test_split(y)
features_train, features_test = train_test_split(x)

#####################################################################
# PERCEPTRON
#####################################################################

from sklearn import linear_model

perceptron=linear_model.Perceptron()

perceptron.fit(features_train, labels_train)

perc_pred=perceptron.predict(features_test)

print sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score(labels_test, perc_pred, normalize=True, sample_weight=None)
print 'perceptron'

#####################################################################
# KNN classifier
#####################################################################
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
knn = KNeighborsClassifier()
knn.fit(features_train, labels_train) 


knn_pred = knn.predict(features_test)


# Accuraatheid

print sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score(labels_test, knn_pred, normalize=True, sample_weight=None) 
print 'knn'


#####################################################################
## SVC
#####################################################################

from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn import svm
svm2 = SVC(kernel="linear")


svm2 = svm.SVC()
svm2.fit(features_train, labels_train)  
SVC(C=1.0, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0, degree=3,
gamma=1.0, kernel='linear', max_iter=-1, probability=False, 
random_state=None,
shrinking=True, tol=0.001, verbose=False)



svc_pred = svm2.predict(features_test)

print sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score(labels_test, svc_pred, normalize=True, 
sample_weight=None)

#####################################################################
# Decision tree
#####################################################################
from sklearn import tree
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = clf.fit(features_train, labels_train)

tree_pred=clf.predict(features_test)

# Accuraatheid

print sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score(labels_test, tree_pred, normalize=True, 
sample_weight=None)
print 'tree'

#####################################################################
# Naive bayes
#####################################################################


import sklearn
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
clf = GaussianNB()
clf.fit(features_train, labels_train)

print "training time:", round(time()-t0, 3), "s"


GaussianNB()
bayes_pred = clf.predict(features_test)



print sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score(labels_test, bayes_pred, 
normalize=True, sample_weight=None)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to use [train_test_split](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.train_test_split.html) the wrong way.

```
labels_train, labels_test = train_test_split(y)      #WRONG
features_train, features_test = train_test_split(x)  #WRONG
```

the splitting of your labels and data isn't necessary the same. One easy way to split your data manually:

```
randomvec=np.random.rand(len(data))  
randomvec=randomvec>0.5

train_data=data[randomvec]
train_label=labels[randomvec]
test_data=data[np.logical_not(randomvec)]
test_label=labels[np.logical_not(randomvec)]
```

or to use the scikit method properly:

```
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.5, random_state=42)
```

Comment: Thanks you so much! I used the last method and it worked great. You helped me out a lot.